# Trying to get a property of a non object in middleware Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3, laravel-middleware

I am having a strange issue in a middleware where the line with `return $next($request);` is throwing a `Trying to get a property of a non object` error but only on my production server I cannot recreate this issue locally.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class NotSubscribed
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (isSubscribed($request->user()) || getOrganisation()->skip_plan) {
                flashError('You already have a subscription to Tradesoft.');
                return redirect(url(''));
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the error message was misleading the issue was actually in a view.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a double-error and I'm not sure why the closure's breaking in the middleware. For me the problem was also in a view. If you look at the detailed stack trace, you'll (hopefully) see another ErrorException, this time in a view file. The line number for me was given for the processed view file (storage/framework/views/bdd1ab3cd9b17fa33f375bec31b7efe831671aac.php:12).